# Двоеточие или тире, что правильнее?

Tags: пунктуация

Совсем недавно я понял, что мне мешало всё это время (: или —) надежда. Что правильнее поставить и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Совсем недавно я понял, что мне мешало всё это время, — надежда.*** 
Тире ставится на месте недостающей части предложения: Ср.:***Совсем недавно я понял, что мне мешало всё это время: [мне мешала] надежда.*** Но в нашем случае слов ***мне мешала*** после придаточного нет, хотя они подразумеваются. Поэтому запятой завершаем придаточное, после запятой двоеточие не ставится - ставим тире на месте пропущенных членов предложения ***мне мешала***.

Comment: Екатерина, я уж хотел порадоваться, что все так просто насчет тире после запятой, да засомневался. Вы уверены, что тут запятая нужна? Просветите, почему "надежда" у вас выскочила за пределы придаточной части?! Можно наверное так трактовать, но уж очень странно считать это само собой разумеющимся...

Comment: Так ведь НАДЕЖДА - это отдельное предложение. Запятая нужна, чтобы завершить придаточное перед следующим предложением. А тире после запятой ставится в несколькиих случаях. Поищу статью, там есть что-то похожее.

Comment: Ах, вон оно как вы трактуете. Нет, я не рассматривал как отдельное предложение. В голову бы не пришло. Тогда это уже третий вариант разбора. Ладно, не в форме я сегодня. Не буду грузить.

Answer (score 0):

Тире, думаю. Двоеточие в подобных случаях (когда нет перечисления) безнадежно устаревает. Хотя, возможно, я тут чего-то не учитываю, меня всегда смущали отсылки к "практике использования" взамен точных формулировок. Но таковы реалии, что тире в некоторых случаях вытесняет двоеточие - и это один из таких случаев.